# How can i reduce the running time of the program in Abaqus python?

Tags: python, abaqus

It is taking more time, when i have more elements. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!
elements  =   odb.rootAssembly.instances[instanceName].elements

```
   en=[]
   nn=[]
   for elem in elements:
       e=elem.label
       n = elem.connectivity
       en.append(e)
       nn.append(n)
   eLn = numpy.array(en)
   nLn = numpy.array(nn)
```

Comment: You can't vectorize for loop here. Your option is to think again why do you need lists/arrays of elements labels and their connectovity and maybe change the approach. Btw, you can append directly to the numpy array.

Comment: yes, i changed my approach to  directly append to the array, but it is taking more time. Is there any possiblity to reduce the time?

Comment: I thin, you can simply read it from input file. And if you don't have input file corresponding to ODB file, then you can create input file from the ODB itself. And all this you can automate using Abaqus python.

Comment: @Chandra, as I said above: you can't vectorize this for loop. Or change the approach of what you are doing (you haven't answered why do you need these lists/arrays) or accept the working time.

Comment: @Roman Zhuravlev, I want to use label and connectivities data of the elements for the comparison of the nodes and also to calculate some quantities, for that I am storing them in arrays so that the code will be faster.

Comment: @Chandra I don't know how many elements you have (if the count goes to the order of 10^6-10^8 then again you probably should think about something more intelligent then just looping through all elements), but generally the biggest gain of numpy is in matrix algebra implementation. Gain in access in reading and writing would be marginal. Also, for the question as it is now - it is not Abaqus related.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use list comprehensions, but even so your runtime is still going to be proportional to the length of the list.

```py
en = [e.label for e in elements]
nn = [n.connectivity for n in elements]
```

is likely worse, because you're iterating over `elements` twice.

Perhaps if you explain what you're trying to achieve with this minimal snippet we could help you more.

I'm uncertain what value the calls to `numpy.array()` give you.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for  your answer. I made it in my code but it is still taking more time.  Actually, am getting the element label and connectivites, and and storing them into a list and am changing list to numpy array, so that it is faster.